# Pygame Python window stops responding

Tags: python, pygame

Good day. I am using Pygame with Python 3.6.5. Here's my code:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if pygame.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    my_change = -15

my += my_change

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(24)
```

My problem is, that when I add

```
running = True
while running:
```

To the top of that code, and then run it, my window just stops responding, even though I added just, like, *2 lines of code!*

P.S: I have no code to break out of this *yet*. Could this be one possible reason for this? I *do* de-indent later on in the code, though, so it only runs for a short period of time. Also: This is all actually in my *main game loop.* Also: My sprite, Super Mario, just falls right through my ground.

Any help or ideas on this and/or how to fix this issue?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Question: Do you have any code to break out of this loop? (i.e do you ever set `running` to false or `break`?)

Comment: No. Not yet, anyways.

Comment: I feel like this question lacks enough context since I can't really see an issue with the snippet you posted (unless it's the only snippet, then there are a lot of problems ;P). Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't, though. Even though there is lots of overall code, this is the only *relevant* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a problem with your loops.

In a pygame loop:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

As you can see, it is an infinite loop. Then, the problem happens in here:

```
running = True
while running:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if pygame.key == pygame.K_UP:
            my_change = -15
```

With this, you create another infinite loop within the main loop. So, this code will never get to updating you pygame window (as it is stuck in the nested loop).

Remember, updating in pygame should go in a single operation only. As that operation will be repeated for every loop in the main game loop. Try revising your code with this in mind. The way it is now, your code will not work no matter how we arrange it.

Tip:
For character motion, creating a class to handle your character, and adding a function for it to update it's position is the most common approach in my opinion.

Possible fix:
Move *running* outside the event loop. Then, add running as another check in your keydown event.

```
running = True
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if running and event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.key == pygame.K_UP:
                my_change = -15
    my += my_change
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What should I do, then?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `for event in pygame.event.get():` before your

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if pygame.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    my_change = -15
```

So that it becomes:

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if pygame.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    my_change = -15
```

According to the [Pygame Documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html), "Pygame handles all its event messaging through an event queue. The routines in this module help you manage that event queue. The input queue is heavily dependent on the pygame display module. If the display has not been initialized and a video mode not set, the event queue will not really work."

By calling "pygame.event.get()", "this will get all the messages and remove them from the queue. If a type or sequence of types is given only those messages will be removed from the queue.

If you are only taking specific events from the queue, be aware that the queue could eventually fill up with the events you are not interested."

Comment: All of this is in my *main game loop.* Also: Now it just prints out 6 events, and stops. It doesn't even hang, to notify that there is a problem.

Comment: I see! Are you updating your display?

If not, add "pygame.display.update()"

Comment: Where? Right after this, I already have this command. Please view my *reviewed edit*.